# Start from a specific column and traverse upto a specific number of columns based on conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the below data in wide format where each row represents a showroom, Quarter is from which quarter the showroom started selling and Starting Year is the Financial Year of Start.

```
Code    Quarter StartingYear Quarter1_Num.FY16-17 Quarter2_Num.FY16-17 Quarter3_Num.FY16-17 Quarter4_Num.FY16-17 Quarter1_Num.FY17-18 Quarter2_Num.FY17-18 Quarter3_Num.FY17-18 Quarter4_Num.FY17-18 
S2249       2   FY16-17         0                       23                  0                   0                   2                       0                   6                   0
S463        3   FY17-18         0                       0                   4                   0                   0                       4                   90                  8
```

For each agent, I have to start from the column based on Quarter & Starting Year (Quarter2_Num.FY16-17 for row1) and cover a period of a year which in this case would mean Quarter2_Num.FY17-18.
As can be seen the column names are based on the Quarter and StartingYear.

Ouput I am trying to get:

```
Code    Quarter1_Starting_Num Quarter2_Starting_Num Quarter3_Starting_Num Quarter4_Starting_Num Quarter5_Starting_Num
S2249       23                  0                       0                   2                       0
S463        4                   0                       0                   4                       90
```

The columns capture data for a year across the quarters after the showroom started.

I know that using gsub I can get the columns containing FY16-17 or FY17-18.
But I am not sure how to specify the starting column for each row and then traversal for N rows.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Why for 2nd row output starts from column `Quarter3_Num.FY16-17` when it has `Quarter = 3` and  `StartingYear = FY17-18 ` ?

Comment: Are the colums of your dataframe always in the correct order (q1.y1, q2,y1, q3,y1, q4.y1, q1.y2 and so on)?

Comment: Hello @TinglTanglBob.. yes it is always ordered similarly

Comment: Hello @RonakShah.. The columns in the output dataframe represent the values of a year from starting period as defined as Quarter and FY. So it captures first quarter of start values, second quarter from start values and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we transfer the data set from wide to long then do our calculations and filters finally transform it back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df, k,val,-c(Code,Quarter,StartingYear)) %>% 
mutate(Quar=gsub('Quarter(\\d)_.*','\\1',k),year=gsub('Quarter\\d_Num\\.(.*)\\.(.*)','\\1-\\2',k)) %>% 
arrange(Code) %>% group_by(Code) %>% 
mutate(flag=cumsum(cumsum(Quarter==Quar & StartingYear==year)), Quarter1=paste0('Quarter',flag,'_Starting_Num')) %>% 
filter(between(flag,1,5)) %>% select(Code,Quarter1,val) %>% spread(Quarter1,val)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   Code [2]
   Code  Quarter1_Starting_Num Quarter2_Starting_Num Quarter3_Starting_Num Quarter4_Starting_Num Quarter5_Starting_Num
  <fct>                 <int>                 <int>                 <int>                 <int>                 <int>
1 S2249                    23                     0                     0                     2                     0
2 S463                      4                     0                     0                     4                    90
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Code = structure(1:2, .Label = c("S2249", "S463"
), class = "factor"), Quarter = 2:3, StartingYear = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "FY16-17", class = "factor"), Quarter1_Num.FY16.17 = c(0L, 
0L), Quarter2_Num.FY16.17 = c(23L, 0L), Quarter3_Num.FY16.17 = c(0L, 
4L), Quarter4_Num.FY16.17 = c(0L, 0L), Quarter1_Num.FY17.18 = c(2L, 
0L), Quarter2_Num.FY17.18 = c(0L, 4L), Quarter3_Num.FY17.18 = c(6L, 
90L), Quarter4_Num.FY17.18 = c(0L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

PS: I changed `S463 3  FY17-18` to `S463 3 FY16-17` to match the expected output, you can keep `S463 3  FY17-18` but you will get NAs for Q3 to Q5

```
gsub('Quarter(\\d)_.*','\\1',c('Quarter1_Num.FY16.17','Quarter4_Num.FY17.18'))
[1] "1" "4"
```

`'Quarter(\\d)_.*'` group the one digit i.e. 1-9 after Quarter and before _ and return that group using `\\1`

```
gsub('Quarter\\d_Num\\.(.*)\\.(.*)','\\1-\\2',c('Quarter1_Num.FY16.17','Quarter4_Num.FY17.18'))
[1] "FY16-17" "FY17-18"
```

`\\.` skip a literal dot after Quarter followed by a digit_Num. In a regular expression, we skip special characters like `.` using `\\`

`(.*)` group anything after dot and before the next dot in one group i.e. FY16 and FY17. `gsub` will consider this as group 1

`\\.` skip a literal dot

`(.*)` group anything after dot in one group i.e. 17 and 18, `gsub` will consider this as group 2

`\\1-\\2` return group 1 and group 2 separted by `-` i.e. FY16-17

Comment: Hi @A Suliman.. Can you please explain the gsub part:
mutate(Quar=gsub('Quarter(\\d)_.*','\\1',k),year=gsub('Quarter\\d_Num\\.(.*)\\.(.*)','\\1-\\2',k)) %>% . I might want to vary this code month wise too in place of Quarter hence I would request you to kindly explain what is the code doing!

Comment: @ShuvayanDas you're most welcome. Please see my update, let me know if you need more elaboration.